# How to collect all media file in a mac directory structure?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, find, tar

I'm trying to copy all media files (Mac file type of Image or Movie) to the same directory structure, only taking media files.

1. Is there a more efficient way than what I've got below?
2. Is there a mechanism in Mac OS find to get the type of Image or Movie?
3. Can this be done without an intermediate tar file? (assume 100,000 media files)

Idea is to:

1. Create temporary file list of media files (tar can't take that many files at command line)
2. Create tar file
3. Extract tar file

Thanks for any advice.

```
# $1 is the directory to search for media
# $2 is the output file name
media_list() {
  find $1 -type f \( -iname "*.JPG" -o -iname "*.JPEG" -o -iname "*.NREF" -o -iname "*.TIFF" -o -iname "*.wmv" -o -iname "*.MOV" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.MPG" -o -iname "*.AVI" -o -iname "*.3g2" -o -iname "*.3gp" -o -iname "*.m4v" \) > $2
}

# $1 is the directory to get media
# $2 is the output tar file name
tar_media() {
  rm file-list.txt
  media_list $1 file-list.txt
  tar -cv -f $2 -I file-list.txt 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Different options:

`mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.movie||kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.image' | parallel cp {} /tmp/{/}`

- parallel can be installed with `brew install parallel`
- `{/}` is the basename

`find . -iname \*.mkv -o -iname \*.jpg | while IFS= read -r f; do cp "$f" /tmp/"${f%%*/}"; done`

- read strips characters in IFS from the start and end of lines
- `read -r` disables interpreting backslashes
- `${f%%*/}` removes the longest `*/` pattern from the start

`shopt -s globstar extglob nocaseglob; for f in **/*.@(mkv|jpg); do cp "$f" "/tmp/${f%%*/}"; done`

- `globstar` (added in bash 4.0) makes `**` match multiple levels of directories
- `extglob` adds support for `@(pat1|pat2)` (exactly one)
- `nocaseglob` makes globs case-insensitive

`f() { cp "$1" "/tmp/${1%%*/}"; }; export -f f; gfind . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(mkv|jpg)' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'f "$1"' _`

- OS X's find doesn't support extended regex, so the command uses GNU find
- `export -f` and `bash -c` are needed to run the function with xargs
- `xargs -n1` takes one argument at a time

Comment: There's no `parallel` on OS X by default. It'd also help if you explained what these options do.

Comment: It would be great to list the pros and cons of those, especially with external USB drives with huge numbers of files.